# In which cases we need to synchronize a method?

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

Let's say I have the following code in Java

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }
}
```

And I create two threads T1 and T2

```
Thread T1 = new Thread(c1);
Thread T2 = new Thread(c2);
```

Where c1 and c2 are two different instances of the class SynchronizedCounter.
It is really needed to synchronize the method increment? Because I know that when we use a synchronized method, the thread hold a lock on the object, in this way other threads cannot acquire the lock on the same object, but threads "associated" with other objects can execute that method without problems. Now, because I have only one thread associated with the object c1, it is anyway needed to use the synchronized method? Also if no other threads associated with the same object exist?

Comment: Depends. How many instances of `SynchronizedCounter` did you create? One or two?

Comment: FWIK there's no reason to synchronize on an `int`

Comment: @JimGarrison 2 instances, c1 and c2

Comment: @fantaghirocco why?

Comment: an `int` is represented by a *DWORD* and the read/write operation on it are performed atomically

Comment: @fantaghirocco Sorry, that is incorrect.  An `int` can be partially updated, which is the reason for classes like `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @ElenaFranchini If you have two instances then you have 2 independent counters accessed by 2 independent threads. They won't interfere.  If you launched 2 threads using the same counter and invoked `increment` in both threads you'd need to synchronize.  Please study https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: @Jim thanks, I wrote *FWIK* just because not 100% sure. This is consistent in Delphi and I wrongly assume it was the same in Java

Comment: @JimGarrison no, `int` is atomic in java, guaranteed. Read the spec. AtomicInteger exists because `incrementAndGet` and `compareAndSet` are useful methods, and `int` doesn't have them.

Comment: @fantaghirocco A Java `int` is a word as defined by the JVM and will always be atomically updated. A Java `long` is two JVM words.

Comment: @fantaghirocco yes you **do** need to synchronise on an `int` you are incrementing, because incrementation is *not* an a atomic operation: it takes 3 steps (read, increment, write), and is thus not threadsafe.

Comment: @rzwitserloot while the *write* is atomic, incrementation (by any means, including `i++`) is *not* atomic. See previous comment.

Comment: @JimGarrison no, an `int` cannot be “partially updated”, but nevertheless incrementation is *not* atomic - *that’s* why AtomicInteger exists; to offer a atomic incrementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, `synchronized` is not needed because each thread has its own instance of the class, so there is no data "sharing" between them.

If you change your example to:

```
Thread T1 = new Thread(c);
Thread T2 = new Thread(c);
```

Then you need to synchronize the method because the `++` operation is not atomic and the instance is shared between threads.

The bottom line is that your class is not thread safe without `synchronized`. If you never use a single instance across threads it doesn't matter. There are plenty of legitimate use cases for classes which are not thread safe. But as soon as you start sharing them between threads all bets are off (i.e. vicious bugs may appear randomly).

Comment: So we can also say that theoretically the fields are not shared in the example that I wrote? Because I have only two threads on two different instances

Comment: It's not theoretical: they really are not shared in your example.

Answer (score 0):

*Given* code/example does not need synchronization since it is using two distinct instances (and so, variables). But if you have one instance shared between two or more threads, synchronization is needed, despite comments stating otherwise.

Actually it is very simple to create a program to show that behavior:

- removed `synchronized`
- added code to call the method from two threads

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        var counter = new SynchronizedCounter();
        var t1 = create(100_000, counter);
        var t2 = create(100_000, counter);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        // wait termination of both threads
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println(counter.c);
    }

    private static Thread create(int count, SynchronizedCounter counter) {
        return new Thread(() -> {
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                counter.increment();
            }
            System.out.println(counter.c);
        });
    }
}
```

Eventually (often?) this will result in *weird* numbers like:

```
C:\TMP>java SynchronizedCounter.java
122948
136644
136644
```

add `synchronized` and output should always end with `200000`:

```
C:\TMP>java SynchronizedCounter.java
170134
200000
200000
```

<sub>Apparently posted code is not complete: the incremented variable is `private` and there is no method to retrieve the incremented value. impossible to really know if the method must be `synchronized` or not.</sub>